# Phantom syntax errors in Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, syntax-error

I just started learning C++, and I'm getting weird 'phantom' syntax errors in Visual C++ 2010 Express.

There are red lines under seemingly random pieces of code, and when I hover my cursor over them it shows errors that seem to make no sense at all. However, when I hit F5 the program compiles and runs successfully.

It's hard to learn C++ like this because I can't quickly distinguish between real syntax errors and 'fake' ones.

**The syntax errors:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0UbD.png

**The program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include "windows.h"

class test2
{
    public:
    int i;
};
class testc
{
    public:
    test2 hi;
};

int main()
{
    testc hello;
    hello.hi.i = 23;
    std::cout << hello.hi.i << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled entire Visual Studio, not just Visual C++. Now it works correctly.